# Access Minikube Loadbalancer Service From Host Machine

Tags: kubernetes, load-balancing, minikube

I am trying to learn how to use Kibernetes with Minikube and have the following deployment and service:

```
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: exampleservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    # Port accessible inside cluster
    port: 8081
    # Port to forward to inside the pod
    targetPort: 8080
    # Port accessible outside cluster
    nodePort: 30002
  type: LoadBalancer
---
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: myappdeployment
spec:
  replicas: 5
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: myapp
        image: tutum/hello-world
        ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
```

I expect to be able to hit this service from my local machine at

```
http://192.168.64.2:30002
```

As per the command: `minikube service exampleservice --url` but when I try to access this from the browser I get a site cannot be reached error.

Some information that may help debugging:

`kubectl get services --all-namespaces`:

```
NAMESPACE     NAME                   TYPE           CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default       exampleservice         LoadBalancer   10.104.248.158   <pending>     8081:30002/TCP           26m
default       kubernetes             ClusterIP      10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                  2h
default       user-service-service   LoadBalancer   10.110.181.202   <pending>     8080:30001/TCP           42m
kube-system   kube-dns               ClusterIP      10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   2h
kube-system   kubernetes-dashboard   ClusterIP      10.110.65.24     <none>        80/TCP                   2h
```

I am running minikube on OSX.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can use **External IPs**, as described in [k8s docs](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#external-ips). Update the service as shown below (where I assume `192.168.64.2` is your minikube IP):

```
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: exampleservice
spec:
  selector:
    app: myapp
  ports:
  - protocol: "TCP"
    # Port accessible inside cluster
    port: 8081
    # Port to forward to inside the pod
    targetPort: 80
    # Port accessible outside cluster
    nodePort: 30002
  type: LoadBalancer
  externalIPs:
  - 192.168.64.2
```

Now you can access your application at http://192.168.64.2:8081/

---

If you need to access the application at 30002, you can use it like this

```
    kind: Service
    apiVersion: v1
    metadata:
      name: exampleservice
    spec:
      selector:
        app: myapp
      ports:
      - protocol: "TCP"
        # Port accessible inside cluster
        port: 8081
        # Port to forward to inside the pod
        targetPort: 80
        # Port accessible outside cluster
        nodePort: 30002
      type: NodePort
```

---

Your deployment file does not look correct to me.

delete it
`kubectl delete deploy/myappdeployment`

use this to create again.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  labels:
    app: myapp
  name: myappdeployment
spec:
  replicas: 5
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: myapp
  strategy: {}
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: myapp
    spec:
      containers:
      - image: tutum/hello-world
        name: myapp
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

Answer (score 10):

**NOTE:** Minikube support LoadBalancer services (via `minikube tunnel`)

you can get the IP and port through which you
can access the service by running

`minikube service kubia-http #=> To open a browser with an IP and port`

**OR**

`minikube service kubia --url #=> To get the IP and port in the terminal`