# Difficulty accessing Minikube-deployed MinIO service from a different machine

Tags: kubernetes, minikube, minio

I have set up Minikube in a VM (ubuntu OS) and deployed MinIO using the following YAML file:

```
# Deploys a new Namespace for the MinIO Pod
apiVersion: v1
kind: Namespace
metadata:
  name: minio-dev
  labels:
    name: minio-dev
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: minio
  namespace: minio-dev
  labels:
    app: minio
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      name: minio
      labels:
        app: minio
    spec:
      volumes:
        - name: data
          emptyDir:
            sizeLimit: 500Mi
      containers:
        - name: minio
          image: quay.io/minio/minio:latest
          imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
          env:
            - name: MINIO_ACCESS_KEY
              value: "minio"
            - name: MINIO_SECRET_KEY
              value: "minio123"
          livenessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /minio/health/live
              port: 9000
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            periodSeconds: 20
          readinessProbe:
            httpGet:
              path: /minio/health/ready
              port: 9000
            initialDelaySeconds: 120
            periodSeconds: 20
          resources:
            requests:
              memory: "1000Mi"
              cpu: "1000m"
            limits:
              memory: "1500Mi"
              cpu: "1500m"

          volumeMounts:
            - mountPath: /data
              name: data
          command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -c
          args:
              - minio server /data --console-address :9090
      restartPolicy: Always
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: minio
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: minio
  namespace: minio-dev
spec:
  selector:
    app: minio
  ports:
    - port: 9090
      name: console
      nodePort:30000
    - port: 9000
      name: s3
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Following the deployment, I used the `minikube service minio -n minio-dev` command and obtained below output.

| Namespace | Name | TargetPort | URL |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| minio-dev | minio | console/9090 s3/9000 | http://192.168.23.2:30000 http://192.168.23.2:30415 |

Additionally, I ran `minikube tunnel` to expose the LoadBalancer service.

While I can access MinIO using the http://192.168.23.2:30000 within the VM's browser, I am facing difficulty accessing the service from a different machine(outside the VM).

I have checked the firewall(allowed traffic to 30000 port), and Minikube tunnel status (no errors), but I still cannot connect.https://stackoverflow.com/a/55462765/5886417 I changed the yaml file by adding externalIPs (192.168.23.2) according to this answer. But I do not see any luck on that.

Could someone please advise on the steps to ensure proper external access to the MinIO service from a different machine? Are there specific considerations for networking or firewall rules that I might be missing?

Thanks in advance for your assistance!

Comment: Install ngrok and then run ngrok http http://192.168.23.2:30000 to expose that endpoint to other computers

Answer (score 1):

Posting Mr Hackerman's comment as answer:

Install ngrok and then run `ngrok http://192.168.23.2:30000` to expose that endpoint to other computers